# New element is being created on every key up event except first field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a web page where there is a text field. As soon as you press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key in the input text field, a new `<input type="text">` is created. For the first field, it works absolutely fine. However, in the newly created fields, when I press any key (even other than the <kbd>enter</kbd> key), a new element is created. A new field should be created only when the <kbd>enter</kbd> key is pressed.

Basically, my problem is that in the new text fields created, when I press **any** key, a new field is created. What am I doing wrong? I have attached a code snippet to clarify what I am trying to ask:

```js
function newlist(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    var todomain = document.getElementById("todomain");
    var newList = document.createElement("input");
    newList.type = "text";
    newList.className = "todolist";
    newList.onkeyup = function() {
      newlist(event)
    };
    todomain.appendChild(newList);
  }
}
```

```css
.todomain {
  width: 100%;
  height: 92%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.todolist {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div class="todomain" id="todomain">
    <p>Press the enter key in the first text field, and a new field is created. However, pressing any key in the new elements creates another field. Only the enter key should create an element.</p>
    <input type="text" class="todolist" onkeyup="newlist(event)">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have passed the "event" argument of the first input field to all other input field keyup event method. You need to pass the event argument of the respective fields.

```
newList.onkeyup = function(e) {
          newlist(e)
 };
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

```js
function newlist(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    var todomain = document.getElementById("todomain");
    var newList = document.createElement("input");
    newList.type = "text";
    newList.className = "todolist";
    newList.onkeyup = function(e) {
      newlist(e)
    };
    todomain.appendChild(newList);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div class="todomain" id="todomain">
    <p>Press the enter key in the first text field, and a new field is created. However, pressing any key in the new elements creates another field, which should not be there. Only the enter key should create an element.</p>
    <input type="text" class="todolist" onkeyup="newlist(event)">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```